# Is it possible to create new apex:images dynamically? (Apex, or JS)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Every time a user clicks a button on my page, a new image appears. But because I don't know how many times the user will click the button, I need to be able to add apex:images dynamically.

My original solution was to create several apex:images where each would only render when "buttonPressCount ==1,2,3,4,etc..." But I would really like to avoid doing that!

Comment: Do you want avoid multiple clicks on save button ?

Comment: There is no save button. The button that I'm referring to can be clicked as many times as the user likes. Therefore the solution should allow for an extremely large number of images to be dynamically created. @Ratan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a string value dynamically to the `apex:image`, like so:

```
Integer counterId = 0;
public String getImageValue() {
    return '/resource/imagepack/image_'+String.valueOf(counterId)+'.jpg';
}
public void incrementImage() {
    counterId++;
}
```

Then, on your page:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!incrementImage}" />
<apex:image value="{!imageValue}" />
```

Adjust accordingly.

---

Edit: You can show any number of images using `apex:repeat`, as follows:

```
public String[] imageValues = new String[0];
public void addImage() {
    imageValues.add('some string to be used as a url');
}
```

And, on your page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!imageValues}" var="imageValue">
    <apex:image value="{!imageValue}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

You can also add decorations, like perhaps div elements, if you want additional control over the styles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From what I can tell, it looks like this allows for a single image on the page at once. What I need is for every newly created image to stay on the page once created.

Comment: @AlexBrigham I've revised my answer based on your comments. Does this help?

Comment: Ahhh that is a great idea! Thank you I will try this out!